# Include("myTable") in Linq to Entities in Silverlight

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, silverlight

I need help, I have a method to Access to my Orders table:

```
public IQueryable<Orders> GetOrders()
{
    return this.ObjectContext.Orders.Include("UnitDetail");
}
```

it Works very well, and I can see it from the window Data Source, and can see Orders and UnitDetail from here

But I need make some considerations for the selected rows, so I made the next method:

```
public IQueryable<Orders> GetOpenOrders(string _iduni)
{
    ObjectSet<Orders> orders = this.ObjectContext.Orders;
    ObjectSet<Estatus> estatus = this.ObjectContext.Estatus;
    ObjectSet<DetailUnit> units = this.ObjectContext.DetailsUnit;
    ObjectSet<ServiceType> servicetype = this.ObjectContext.ServiceType;

    var query =
      (from o in orders
       join e in estatus on o.ID equals e.IDOrder
       join u in units on o.IDUni equals u.IDUni
       join t in servicetype on u.IDType equals t.IDType
       where o.IDUni.Equals(_iduni)
       && !estatus.Any(oe => (oe.Estatus == "CANCELADA" || oe.Estatus == "CERRADA") 
       && oe.IDOrder == o.ID)
       select o).Distinct();

       return query.AsQueryable();
}
```

This show me the correct recs, but what happend? why I don't see UnitDetail, when I inspect the result UnitDetail is null, how I can do for put the Include clausule in this new method??

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I've just run into this same kind of problem today, `joins` will definitely mess with the `include`. So looking at your code again, what is the purpose of your `joins`, you don't appear to be doing anything with them in your `select` statements. I'd expected to see them play a part in the `where` clause, but none of your restrictions need those joins. What is the purpose of the joins and the variable assignments at top for `estatus`, `units` and `servicetype`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't put the `Include` in your new method anywhere.

EDITED: to remove the unused joins.

You should be able to just use `Include` as you did in your `GetOrders` method, and so have it as a part of your existing `orders` variable. You are not actually using those `joins` anywhere, are you intending to?

Like this:

```
public IQueryable<Orders> GetOpenOrders(string _iduni)
{
    var query =
      (from o in this.ObjectContext.Orders.Include("UnitDetail")
       where o.IDUni.Equals(_iduni) 
           && !this.ObjectContext.Estatus.Any(oe => (oe.Estatus == "CANCELADA" || oe.Estatus == "CERRADA") 
       && oe.IDOrder == o.ID)
       select o).Distinct();

       return query.AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mashton, I try your suggestion, but when I put:     ObjectSet<Orders> orders = this.ObjectContext.Orders.Include("UnitDetail"); system say me "can not convert System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Orders> in System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<Orders>

Comment: Mashton: so I change my query: var query = (from o in this.ObjectContext.Orders.Include("UnitDetail") join e in estatus on o.ID equals u.IDOrder..... select o).Distinct(); return query.AsQueryable(); and it not have error, but when I execute my App "UnitDetail" is null... :(

Comment: Yes Mashton, all is ok because if I use a simple method as it `return this.ObjectContext.Orders.Include("DetailsUnit").Where(o => o.IDUni.Equals(_iduni));` for the same record it Works very well... ?

Comment: and when I use your suggestion `select o).Distinct().Include("UnitDetails");` system say me _System.Linq.IQueryable<MTTO.Web.Orders> not contains an 'Include' definition_

Comment: Sorry, coding blind here - I've moved the `Include` so it is operating on the ObjectContext.Orders.

Comment: Updated answer. If you do need joins, the way we approached it was to create a set of results from the joins before we then created our query-result to return. The query-result part can then safely use `include` because it isn't doing any joins, it is just doing a `where` that has a restriction (such as `contains`) from the results created with the joins.

Comment: Exactly Mashton it is the option I was implemented at the last weekend, I must search if exists a Open Order for the IDUni of Service Type Preventive, for this are the joins, if it exists then the user can update it, if not then can add it, then I implement this `public IQueryable<Orders> GetOpenOrders(string _iduni)
{
    ObjectSet<Orders> orders = this.ObjectContext.Orders;
    ObjectSet<Estatus> Estatus = this.ObjectContext.Estatus;
    ObjectSet<DetailsUnits> units = this.ObjectContext.DetailsUnit;
    ObjectSet<ServiceType> servicetype = this.ObjectContext.ServiceType;`

Comment: `Orders varquery;
varquery =
(from o in orders
join e in Estatus on o.ID equals e.IDOrder
join u in units on o.IDUni equals u.IDUni
join t in servicetype on u.IDType equals t.IDType
where o.IDUni.Equals(_iduni)
&& !Estatus.Any(oe => (oe.Estatus == "CANCELADA" || oe.Estatus == "CERRADA") && oe.IDOrder == o.ID)
select o).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();

    if (varquery != null)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Orders.Include("DetailsUnit").Where(o => o.ID.Equals(varquery.ID));
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}` thanks so much for your valuable help